# Select children outside of range

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to do the following:

```
.feed > :not(:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n+10))
```

But apparently that's not available in css. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to select all elements that aren't the 5th - 10th child of `.feed`. Another way to do that would be to select the 1st-4th child elements, and then the 11th+ child elements.

This will do it:

```
.feed > :nth-child(-n+4), .feed > :nth-child(n+11) {
    ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9ZSeZ/1/

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
.feed > :not(:nth-child(n+5)), .feed > :not(:nth-child(-n+10)) {
    background: red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xacLT/)

**Explanation**

That's because `:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n+10)` means `:nth-child(n+5)` AND `nth-child(-n+10)`.

But according to de Morgan's laws,

> not(A AND B) = not(A) OR not(B)

Then, if you want to negate it, instead of `:not(:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n+10))`, you need the OR operator `,`:

```
:not(:nth-child(n+5)), :not(:nth-child(-n+10))
```